# Transfer from yahoo to google mail

Tags: gmail

Can i transfer messages as well as contacts from yahoo to gmail ? And will the contacts remain in yahoo afterwards so i have a chance to close it in my own time ? Thank you,  Marie

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to export the Contacts from Yahoo, and import them into your Google account.  For email, you can't really transfer, only real way would be to forward email from Yahoo to your Gmail account.

You'd want to do the Contacts transfer when logged into the accounts via a computer.